# Take my help - Who am I?

Tags: riddle

> When you are dangled
>   Take my help so that everything will be clear
>
> I can move very fast
>   But still I can not carry anything
>
> Put some of me in your life
>   And you will be happy that you found your destiny
>
> I might be the way
>  
>   The new generations would want to travel
>
> Sometimes people use me
>   But to demonstrate how far real things are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are

> light

when you are dangled
take my help so that everything will be clear

> When you are dangled it helps to shed light on you situation.

I can move very fast
but still i can not carry anything

> Light moves at the speed of light, but will not carry anything.

put some of me in your life
and you will be happy that you found your destiny

> The light of my life is something (often someone) that makes me really happy.

i might be the way
the new generations would want to travel

> Honestly, I would be scared. But I guess if it ends up being a well tested technology...

sometimes people use me
but to demonstrate how far real things are

> I love to tell little kids, how far the light of a star they look at has traveled. And how long.

Comment: What does "when you are dangled" mean?

Comment: For the travelling part, it could refer to the use of solar power or (less likely) [photon rockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_rocket).